# How to get the extention of an image using PHP?

Tags: php, extension-methods, dir

Is there any way to get the extension of an image without writing its extension?

For example in the code below, i have to write image.GIF to know that it is GIF file.

```
pathinfo('/testdir/dir2/image.gif', PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Comment: So you want to detect the *file format* of an image?

Comment: So you know the name but you don't know the extension in a folder ?

Comment: Yes Jon, that's exactly what I am trying to figure out

Answer (score 1):

I always use this function to find out a files mime type:

```
function validateMimeType($filePath, $extensions) {
    $finfo      = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME);
    $mimeType   = finfo_file($finfo, $filePath);

    finfo_close($finfo);

    return preg_match("/$extensions/i", $mimeType);
}
```

Where $extensions is a string, where you define your wanted formats, like:

```
$extension = "jpg|jpeg|png";
```

Comment: If you want to verify that a file from an untrusted source for instance really is an image, then you use this function. If you only want to find out the extension check out the mime type.

Answer (score 0):

To determine if it's actually a gif, you should request the mimetype:

For example:
http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2010/05/17/how-to-use-php-fileinfo-extension-to-get-file-mime-type/

Answer (score 0):

Using exif_imagetype($file_name) in a switch with cases for the values will get you the ext without having it in the name.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php

Example

```
$type = false;
switch(exif_imagetype($file_name)) {
   case 1:
      $type = 'gif';
   break;
   case 2:
      $type = 'jpeg';
   break;
   case 3:
      $type = 'png';
   break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, no.

If there are 2 images, image.gif and image.jpg, what result would you expect? You want to have information about a file, so you have to call that file by using its name. the extention is part of the name.

You could read all contents of the dir and filter out the files you want.

```
$dir = "/testdir/dir2";
foreach(scandir($dir) as $file)
{
  if(is_dir($file) == false && $file != ".." && $file != ".")
  {
    var_dump(pathinfo(dir . '/' . $file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
  }
}
```

Pathinfo was made to simplify the splitting of a filename into extention and name. It is not to determine filetype, and why would you want to split the name into  parts if you know the name hardcoded?

Answer (score -1):

```
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Getting rid of my 'home brewed code' that got my a downvote for some reason.

The above code may help a bit more?

everyone is right, PHP has it's own devices for this and pathinfo should work fine.

For Reference:

```
function get_file_extension($file_name) {
    return substr(strrchr($file_name,'.'),1);
}
```

Can work as some form of an alternative. without knowing the exact nature of the files to be read it's hard to give an exact answer.

Comment: No, because a) it does not change anything and b) it replaces a perfectly good built-in implementation with a homebrew one (why???)

Comment: Because even though it is a home brew sollution, and even though I am in a way - reinventing the wheel. It still works as a resolution to some problems similar or like this. No need in the downvote because you don't feel it's useful for you. The code given is still useful for others and should be displayed as such.

Comment: I 'm sorry, but I don't consider replicating built-in functionality useful at all. In fact I consider it a detriment, because it is a) slower, b) untested and c) unnecessary code -- therefore bad practice, which we should all be steering people away from. In any case, it is up to *you* to prove that this code offers something new and not up to me or anyone else to prove a negative.